# Core Animation question about swapping views

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, uiview, interface-builder, core-animation

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender 
{
SignView *tempVC = [[SignView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignView" bundle:Nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
[self presentModalViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
[tempVC passDataWithString:button1.titleLabel.text andColor:currentlySelectedColor isNightModeOn:nightMode.on];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

can anyone help me figure out why this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will call beginAnimations: and commitAnimations, which cannot be nested.

```
[self presentModalViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
```

So move it to before beginAnimations: or after commitAnimations.

Comment: Well I moved it to both places and the UIView doesn't curl up like a page turning. The SignView slides into place instead of  Curling into place.